# SwiftUI different actions on the same Custom Alert actions

Tags: swiftui, escaping, action, alert

I created a custom alert. I want the product to be added to the basket when the Ok button on Alert is clicked on the first screen. When the Ok button is pressed on the second screen, the purchase of the product is requested. I called the same alert on 2 pages and I want it to take different actions. I couldn't do that with @Escaping.

**AlertView**

```
struct AlertView: View {
    @Binding var openShowAlert: Bool
    @State var closeShowAlert: Bool = false
    @State var openState: CGFloat = -UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    @State var closeState: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    var title: String = ""
    var message: String = ""
    var okButtonText: String = ""
    var cancelButtonText: String = ""
    
   
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text(title)
                .michromaFont(size: 20)
                .padding(.top)
            Spacer()
            Text(message)
                .michromaFont(size: 18)
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    
                    self.openShowAlert = false
                    openState = -UIScreen.main.bounds.height
                    closeState = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
                    
                }) {
                    Text(cancelButtonText)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                }
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Text(okButtonText)
                }
            }
            .michromaFont(size: 18)
            .padding([.horizontal, .bottom])
        }
        .neumorphisimBackground(width: 300, height: 200)
        .offset(y: self.openShowAlert ? self.openState : self.closeState)
        .animation(.easeInOut)
        
        .onChange(of: self.openShowAlert, perform: { value in
            if value {
                self.openState = .zero
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**DetailView**
On this screen, click Alert presentation to add the product to the cart.

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    var device = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom
    @State var width: CGFloat = 300
    @State var height: CGFloat = 450
    @Binding var text: String
    @State var showAlert: Bool = false

    var body: some View {

        ZStack() {
            ......
            AlertView(openShowAlert: self.$showAlert)
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        
    }
}
```

**CartView** Click I am providing an alert on this screen to purchase the product.

```
struct CartView: View {
    @State var cartList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State var showAlert: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            .....
            AlertView(openShowAlert: self.$showAlert)
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

How can I send two different actions in the same alert.

Comment: Can you include a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I don't see why it shouldn't work with a closure. Have you tried passing over a closure like so?

```
struct AlertView: View {
    ...
    var okButtonAction: () -> ()

    var body: some View {
        ...
        Button(action: okButtonAction) {
            Text(okButtonText)
        }
    }   
}
```

#### Usage

```
AlertView(openShowAlert: self.$showAlert) {
    // Your custom code 
}
```

### Alternative Idea

You could work with `Combine` and create a publisher with a specific key to identify the sender screen. Then you can put your custom code inside `.onReceive()`.